# Inheritance of width. Bxslider

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is a problem. My slider may contain different images, the width of which can be up to 1256px. Slides - about 4.
Under the slider there is a block, whose width should equal the width of the active image. How to do it better?

```
mode: fade
```

I tried this:

```
if ($ ('. carousel. bx-wrapper. item img'). css ('display') == 'block') {
 var widthparent = $ ('. carousel. bx-wrapper. item img'). width ();
 widthparent = widthparent + 'px';
 var child = $ ('. subscribe');
 child.width (widthparent);
}
```

But this solution is bad. 
Here width is inherited from the first image.

---

It works:

```
$('.carousel .list').bxSlider({
 mode: 'fade',

 onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
  var blockWidth = $slideElement.width();
    $('.subscribe').css('width', blockWidth);
 }
});
```

But, at the block ".carousel" width is established "max-width": "1256px" and every .item = 1256px.

It is required that width was taken from the img, not the .item.

Ex., in the second case, ".subscribe" has to equal 1200px.

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;">
    <div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 508px;">
      <ul class="list" style="width: auto; position: relative;">

        <li class="item" style="float: none; list-style: none outside none; position: absolute; display: none; width: 1256px; z-index: 0;">
          <a class="link" href="">
            <img alt="" src="media/uploads/slide-1.jpg"> // width = 1000px
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="item" style="float: none; list-style: none outside none; position: absolute; display: none; width: 1256px; z-index: 0;">
          <a class="link" href="">
            <img alt="" src="media/uploads/slide-2.jpg"> // width = 1200px
          </a>
        </li>

        <li class="item" style="float: none; list-style: none outside none; position: absolute; display: none; width: 1256px; z-index: 0;">
          <a class="link" href="">
            <img alt="" src="media/uploads/slide-3.jpg"> // width = 900px
          </a>
        </li>

        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a code sample to work with, this is my best bet. Inside of your slider call, there's a function called `onSlideBefore`, which could help with what you're trying to do.

```
$('.bx').bxSlider({
    onSlideBefore: function($el, old, new) {
        var blockWidth = $el.eq(new).width();
        $('.subscribe').css('width', blockWidth);
    }
});
```

Without having any code to play with, I'm not 100% sure on this, but it should get you on the right track.